# Is there any way to combine multiple distance metrics in a similarity function?

Tags: similarity, knn, hamming-distance, hungarian-algorithm, mahalanobis

I need to find a way to code a similarity function between two vector(data instances), let's name them [image: x_m] and [image: x_n]. These data instances have categorical features as well as quantities. Thus, I'd like to find a way to combine, let's say Hamming Distance and Euclidean Distance as [image: x_n,x_m] to use it in my association problem.

There are merging types for k-NN, such as voting etc., still association problem cannot be solved by voting approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can you [Gower distance](https://medium.com/@rumman1988/clustering-categorical-and-numerical-datatype-using-gower-distance-ab89b3aa90d9) to find the distance when you have mixed data type.